# How to change data location of podman?

Tags: podman

Followed the information I found, I added `graphroot` and `driver` to /etc/containers/storage.conf. Then removed the default location folder. Ran `podman` with `root` and `storage-driver` parameters. Then `podman info` with no parameter. At this moment, it showed correctly about the new graphRoot.

But then I ran `podman info` again, and it returned to default location. Same thing happened with rootless.

What steps should I take? It is podman 2.0.4 on NixOS.